# Placement of the word "later" in a sentence

Tags: adverbs, word-order

Why is it correct to say "it later came to pass" instead of "it came to pass later"?
What is the rule for this placement?

Answer (score 4):

There is no particular ironclad rule that I can think of, but the first sounds immeasurably better to my ear.

1. It later came to pass that. . . .
2. It came later to pass that. . . .
3. It came to pass later that. . . .

Comment: As far as measure goes, #1 is iambic, #3 is amphibrachic, #2 is not anything in particular I know of.

Comment: Also: *Later it came to pass that* ...

Answer (score 4):

Both are perfectly grammatical.

To me the second construction is in general *hugely* more idiomatic English (*It happened later*). But the first form has a slightly literary or archaic feel, and so matches better with the literary phrase *came to pass*.

Answer (score 3):

Neither is necessarily incorrect; I also can't imagine that one is necessarily worse, at least without knowing the context.

The semantic distinction between the two (putting aside the different poetic properties that StoneyB mentions) is a subtle one of emphasis.

- [**It later came to pass...**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20later%20came%20to%20pass%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)  This phrase is somewhat of an idiom in English, a familiar phrase.  It recalls a story-telling tone, and expresses a segue as from one time period to another.
- [**It came to pass later...**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20came%20to%20pass%20later%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)  Here the *later* does (granted) feel a bit out of place, and as such the phrase seems to emphasize the *later* condition of whatever *it* is, rather than *it* itself.